# Typescript extending a generic typed class

Tags: typescript

This is the class that I want to extend

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { IRepository, IFireOrmQueryLine, IOrderByParams, IEntity } from './types';
import { AbstractFirestoreRepository } from './AbstractFirestoreRepository';
import { TransactionRepository } from './Transaction/BaseFirestoreTransactionRepository';
export declare class BaseFirestoreRepository<T extends IEntity> extends AbstractFirestoreRepository<T> implements IRepository<T> {
    private readonly firestoreColRef;
    constructor(colName: string, collectionPath?: string);
    findById(id: string): Promise<T>;
    create(item: T): Promise<T>;
    update(item: T): Promise<T>;
    delete(id: string): Promise<void>;
    runTransaction<R>(executor: (tran: TransactionRepository<T>) => Promise<R>): Promise<R>;
    createBatch(): import("./Batch/FirestoreBatchSingleRepository").FirestoreBatchSingleRepository<T>;
    execute(queries: Array<IFireOrmQueryLine>, limitVal?: number, orderByObj?: IOrderByParams, single?: boolean): Promise<T[]>;
}
```

as you can see, it has `T` that extends to an IEntity

Currently, here's my code

```
import { BaseFirestoreRepository, IEntity } from 'fireorm'

interface ICustomRepository<T extends IEntity> {
  where(filter: any): BaseFirestoreRepository<T>
}

BaseFirestoreRepository.prototype.where = function () {}
```

I am not sure it is correct because I didnt pass the type when I do the `prototype` and also the `where` shows an error the `Property 'where' does not exist on type 'BaseFirestoreRepository<any>'`

My end goal here is to use this function similar to this c# extension

```
public static IQueryable<T> OrderByPropertyName<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string attribute, string direction) {
    // my logic here
}
```

where I can directly add the method in the class similar to how prototype works

Comment: Why instead of using prototype you simply not declare it as `class CustomRepository extends BaseFirestoreRepository`?

Answer (score 0):

```
interface ICustomRepository<T extends IEntity> 
  extends BaseFirestoreRepository<T> {
  ...
}
```